# Why can't the ancient directory be a symlink?

Tags: go-ethereum

[This line of code in geth shuts down with an error, if `ancient` is a symlink.](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/rawdb/freezer.go#L97)

What's the purpose of this?

Alternative ways to move the `ancient` directory are a bind mount, or the `--datadir.ancient` flag.

Answer (score -1):

the ancient directory cannot be a symlink in geth for security reasons. While symlinks can be useful in some cases, they can also be used by attackers to manipulate the file system in unexpected ways.

Comment: what ways? There are no attacker-controlled filenames in geth.